# Any way to re-enable OK Google in Chrome for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, google-search

I'm using the latest version of Chrome on Windows 10 and would like to enable voice activated "OK Google" search that is always on.

Anyway to do this? Any extensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is "No".

This was a [feature](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-enable-ok-google-hands-free-voice-search-in-google-chrome/) introduced in May of 2014, but Google [removed it from Chrome](http://www.theverge.com/2015/10/16/9553051/ok-google-removed-from-chrome-46-desktop) in the fall of 2015 because it was under utilized.

As far as I can find, Google has not replaced this with any other feature or app.

Comment: I know it was removed but is there a way to re-enable it with a settings flag, an extension, or a patch, etc.?

Comment: As far as I know, you can not.